# disabling imageSmoothingEnabled by default on multiple canvases

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm creating a browser-based game that uses layered canvases and sprite images, and for visual and performance reasons I would like to disable imageSmoothingEnabled by default. It's my understanding that imageSmoothingEnabled isn't available in all browsers, but there are vendor-prefixed versions. I am trying to find an elegant way to disable this attribute  by default across all my canvases (in as many browsers as possible). So far, this is my method:

```
context1.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context1.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context1.oImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context1.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

context2.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context2.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context2.oImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context2.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

context3.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context3.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context3.oImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context3.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
//etc...
```

Is there a more elegant approach? Is it perhaps possible to change the context's API to default to false, before actually creating each canvas context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have a cleaner approach : since you will always get a context by using `getContext('2d')` on a canvas, you can inject `getContext`, so that it does any setup of your like before returning the context.

The following piece of code successfully sets the smoothing to false for all your contexts :

(it should, quite obviously, be run before any call to getContext).

```
// save old getContext
var oldgetContext = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext ;

// get a context, set it to smoothed if it was a 2d context, and return it.
function getSmoothContext(contextType) {
  var resCtx = oldgetContext.apply(this, arguments);
  if (contextType == '2d') {
   setToFalse(resCtx, 'imageSmoothingEnabled');
   setToFalse(resCtx, 'mozImageSmoothingEnabled');
   setToFalse(resCtx, 'oImageSmoothingEnabled');
   setToFalse(resCtx, 'webkitImageSmoothingEnabled');  
  }
  return resCtx ;  
}

function setToFalse(obj, prop) { if ( obj[prop] !== undefined ) obj[prop] = false; }

// inject new smoothed getContext
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = getSmoothContext ;
```

Rq that you can do anything in 'your' getContext. I use it to copy canvas's width, height on the context to have them at hand with no DOM access, among other things.

Comment: Clever way to customize getContext, I'll be sure to use this method in new ways. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can put those into a method like:

```
function imageSmoothingEnabled(ctx, state) {
    ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = state;
    ctx.oImageSmoothingEnabled = state;
    ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = state;
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = state;
}
```

then call for each context:

```
imageSmoothingEnabled(context1, false);
imageSmoothingEnabled(context2, false);
imageSmoothingEnabled(context3, false);
```

As these are properties you can't simply alter their defaults. The method here is pretty clean - it can be cleaner by checking the existence of the property first:

```
if (typeof ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled !== 'undefined')
    ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = state;
```

etc.