# Blurred square on canvas. What to do?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Why blurred square on canvas? If you look closely you will see that the image is fuzzy and blurred. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yydok7tv/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var mx=0,my=0;
var rect = {
x: 0,
y: 0,
w: 30,
h: 30,
s: 5
}
rect.update = function(x,y){
this.targetX = x;
this.targetY = y;
var tx = this.targetX - this.x;
var ty = this.targetY - this.y;
var dist = Math.sqrt(tx*tx+ty*ty);
this.velX = (tx/dist)*this.s;
this.velY = (ty/dist)*this.s;
if(dist>this.w/2){
this.x += this.velX;
this.y += this.velY;
}
}
canvas.addEventListener('click',function(e){
mx = e.clientX;
my = e.clientY;
});
function paint(){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
ctx.fillRect(rect.x,rect.y,rect.w,rect.h);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
rect.update(mx,my);
window.requestAnimationFrame(paint);
};
paint();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your x,y are integers:

```
this.x = parseInt(this.x+this.velX);
this.y = parseInt(this.y+this.velY);
```

Comment: I would recommend changing the drawing code, not the positioning. If you change the line in the `paint()` function to this: `ctx.fillRect(Math.floor(rect.x),Math.floor(rect.y),rect.w,rect.h);`, then you can still have fractional locations, but the box is still not anti-aliased.

Comment: @zrneely Sure, sounds good.  The important thing is that the drawing is done on integer boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your objects coords as integers as @markE says, and you could also try to set imageSmoothing to false:
[disable image smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003687/disabling-imagesmoothingenabled-by-default-on-multiple-canvases)

Hope it helps.