# html2canvas: image look blurred on firefox

Tags: javascript, canvas, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas library to generate images from a specific div with informations inserted by users

```
$('#generate').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var x=document.getElementById("signature");

        html2canvas(x).then(function(canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            $('#image').fadeIn(200).attr('src', data);
        });
});
```

On Windows Chrome, the generated canvas look fine. But on Firefox, the logo image and html text inside canvas look so blurred.

**UPDATE**

If I change var x by `document.body`, the canvas look better. But I need just the specific div.

[image]

Comment: I noticed you reference "signature" which lead me to think, provided it is a JS based signature "applet" we're talking about, that you could just grab its canvas directly instead of going by html2canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Chained methods can be messy when one of them is asychronous. Try this:

```
    html2canvas(x).then(function(canvas) {
        var data = canvas.toDataURL();
        $('#image').attr('src', data);
        $('#image').fadeIn(200);
    });
```

Comment: No result. But if I change the var x by document.body, the canvas looks better. The problem is that I need just a div.

Answer (score 0):

Have also experienced this problem: solved by disabling the image smoothing (see also [disabling imageSmoothingEnabled by default on multiple canvases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003687/disabling-imagesmoothingenabled-by-default-on-multiple-canvases/22018649#22018649))

Comment: Hi Kim, good first post. I would like to point out, however, that you'll be more likely to receive up-votes / accepts with a more detailed answer.